# SQL connection string issue in SQL Server 2014 if we set Column Encryption Setting=enabled;

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

To resolve the checkmarx issue(Missing column encryption) we have added Column Encryption Setting=enabled; to our SQL connection string as below.

```
Data Source =Localhost; Initial Catalog = SQLDB; Integrated Security = True;Column Encryption Setting=enabled;
```

It is working fine with SQL Server 2019 but with SQL Server 2014 we are getting the below exception.

> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: SQL Server instance in
> use does not support column encryption

We found that the Column Encryption Setting was introduced with SQL Server 2016 version.

Any suggestion how we can solve the issue in SQL Server 2014 or lower versions.

**Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: SQL Server instance in use does not support column encryption.
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryProcessFeatureExtAck(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, Boolean disableTnir)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
**

Comment: upgrade would be the easiest solution

Comment: That or, you know, just don't use the feature, if you can actually live without it. :P Nothing compels you to add `Column Encryption Setting=enabled` to your connection string (and if you need to do so dynamically, you can use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`).

Comment: Remove `;Column Encryption Setting=enabled;` from the connection string when you need to connect to a SQL Server 2014. Not sure what the question is here, you should be able to see the options you have available to you, or there is something you've not told us. You can either *not* ask SQL Server to enable column level encryption, or you can upgrade to a newer version of SQL Server that supports it.

Comment: If the requirement to use column level encryption comes from that checkmarkx report, and you want to follow that, then clearly you cannot keep using SQL Server 2014 and will be forced to upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: Note that column-level encryption is a very specific thing requiring configuration on the database end as well (Always Encrypted), makes certain operations impossible if columns are encrypted, and cannot apply in general to every application. Make sure you are not confusing this with the `Encrypt=Yes` setting, which merely enforces connection-level encryption and is supported by all supported versions of SQL Server. That setting makes a lot more sense as a blanket recommendation, whereas turning on Always Encrypted only makes things more secure if the feature is actually used.